# XSLT will not sort alphabetically by an xml field

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I am attempting to sort this data by the surname field inside of "ownerName". Is this sort code in the correct place to do that? When i try to run this it gives me a parsing error.

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="storeloation" /><br/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="storeURL" /><br/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="storeDescription" /><br/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="related stores" /><br/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="storecustomerCount" /><br/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="storeVisits" /><br/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="storeestablished" /><br/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ownersProfile/ownersName/firstName"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ownersProfile/ownersName/surname"/>
        <xsl:sort select="surname" /><br/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ownersProfile/ownersEmail"/><br/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ownersProfile/ownersAddress"/><br/>
```

If i'm not mistaken (which i probably am) this sort statement there short sort every instance of the template match by the surname of the owner?

Answer (score 1):

Two errors here.

Firstly, the parsing error is because xsl:sort should be a child of xsl:apply-templates, not a sibling.

Second, the select expression of `xsl:sort` is evaluated with each item in the sequence being sorted as the context node. These items in your case are `surname` elements. I suspect that `surname` elements do not have a child element named `surname`; and that what you intended was `<xsl:sort select="."/>`.

So the correct form is:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="ownersProfile/ownersName/surname">
        <xsl:sort select="." />
</xsl:apply-templates>
<br/>
```

By the way, most of us find it far easier to diagnose "parsing errors" if you tell us what the error was. Saying that something failed without saying how it failed is like telling your doctor you are in pain without saying where the pain is.

== ON REFLECTION... ==

You haven't shown your XML source, but thinking about what the element names might mean, I suspect that there are multiple ownersProfile elements, each with one ownersName, which has one or more firstNames and one surname, plus other properties like email address. In that case you don't want to sort the surnames, you want to sort the profiles. So it becomes something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ownersProfile">
  <xsl:sort select="ownersName/surname"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ownersName/firstName"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ownersName/surname"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ownersEmail"/><br/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ownersAddress"/><br/>
   ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

But I'm completely into the realm of guesswork now.